# Problem with IE8 with ajax and alert

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

i have the following script.

everything works fine in ff, safari.

But in IE the alert ***"Du kannst pro Beitrag nur 1 x voten."*** is not showing

Browser Support Code

```
function voteFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    var TYPE = document.getElementById('TYPE').value;
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    if (ajaxRequest.responseText == 'you voted allready'){alert('Du kannst pro Beitrag nur 1 x voten.')}
                    if (ajaxRequest.responseText != 'you voted allready'){

        document.getElementById('cdm_play_video_votes').innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;}
        if (TYPE == 1 ){publishVideovote();}
                    if (TYPE == 2 ){publishImagevote();}

    }


}

var videoid = document.getElementById('videoid').value;
    var userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
var queryString = "?function=vote&videoid=" + videoid + "&userid=" + userid ;

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "function.php" + queryString, true);

ajaxRequest.send(null);
 }

 //-->
```

can anybody help me?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I am not saying you can't do it like this, but there are lot of javascript libs out there which will help do this job much better. We don't need to reinvent the wheel. jQuery is an awesome library.

Comment: thanks a lot. but i have everything setup like this. so if theres a solution why ie8 isn't show the alert this would be perfect.

Comment: What is the ajaxRequest.responseText? Is the status 200? Are you cached with an old response?

Comment: oh, wait, which alert isn't working? the one in your voteFunction? or the one in your AJAX handler?

Comment: the ajaxRequest.responseText is correct. it vote for an image only once, so the responseText is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(removed original answer)

Ok, since the AJAX part works, and just the alert in the handler is failing I would look into the code there.

Using the ID "type", and referencing the **value** of that element with a variable of the **same name** smells like [IE's global namespace pollution](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-162-global-namespace-pollution-in.html) might be affecting your code.

try changing this line from:

```
var TYPE = document.getElementById('TYPE').value;
```

to:

```
var typeValue = document.getElementById('TYPE').value;
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

and then all references to it after wards.

Comment: how can i change this, so it's displayed ?

Comment: @epascarello - thanks I modified my answer, and adjusted the original question to clarify this part.

Comment: @oli - so did this fix the issue? e.g. was it the variable name that was causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Which of the alerts isn't showing? The code you posted contains two, so identifying which section of the code we're supposed to be focusing on would be helpful.

One very small thing that I noticed: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of the second alert - if (ajaxRequest.responseText == 'you voted allready'){alert('Du kannst pro Beitrag nur 1 x voten.')} - which may cause the problem (I'm not sure how picky IE8 is about that kind of thing).

Comment: it's this one 
(ajaxRequest.responseText == 'you voted allready'){alert('Du kannst pro Beitrag nur 1 x voten.')} - so you think it's because of the mssing ;?

Comment: IE will handle the missing ";" just fine in ***this*** particular case ;-)